# 'nuxt-link' redirecting to different address in production server and local server

Tags: nuxt.js

I am adding a blog in my project. I am using `nuxt-link` to redirect me to the new page.
So when I use

```
<nuxt-link :to="`${postData.slug}`">
  CONTINUE READING
</nuxt-link>
```

in my local server it redirects me to `localhost:3000/some-slug`

while in my production server (aws amplify) it redirects to `website.com/blog/some-slug` (this is intended)

Similarly if I go with

```
<nuxt-link :to="`blog/${postData.slug}`">
  CONTINUE READING
</nuxt-link>
```

localserver will push me to `localhost:3000/blog/some-slug`

while production server will redirect me to `website.com/blog/blog/some-slug`

how do i configure my project that I don't have to see this problem?

Comment: seems like `postData.slug` giving different values on local and live. you can simply check by print it anywhere and check if the value is okay or not

Comment: in both the cases I am getting `some-slug` on the console.